# Having trouble forming SQL query

Tags: sql

I have three tables. SurveyFact, Question, and Responses.  The survey fact contains the data for surveys taken by clients while the Question and Responses table has the obvious data, a list of questions and possible responses per Question.

SurveyFact:

```
| SurveyFactID | ClientID   |  QuestionID   | ResponseCode |
------------------------------------------------------------
|    1         |    1       |     1         |     3        |    
|    2         |    1       |     2         |     3        |
|    3         |    1       |     3         |     1        |
```

Question:

```
| QuestionID| QuestionText          |
-------------------------------------
|    1      |    blah blah blah     |    
|    2      |    blah blah blah     |
|    3      |    blah blah blah     |
```

Response:

```
| ResponseID| QuestionID  | ResponseCode |ResponseText     |
-----------------------------------------------------------|
|    1      |    1       |      1       |   like           |    
|    2      |    1       |      2       |   don't care     |
|    3      |    1       |      3       |   hate           |
|    4      |    2       |      1       |   like           |    
|    5      |    2       |      2       |   don't care     |
|    6      |    2       |      3       |   hate           |
```

Here is the query I've come up with.  (That fails)

```
select
    sf.QuestionCode as [Question Number],
    q.QuestionText as [Question Text],
    r.ResponseText as [Reponse]
from SurveyFact sf
inner join Question q
    on q.QuestionID = sf.QuestionID
inner join Responses r
    on r.ResponseCode = sf.ResponseCode
where sf.ClientID = '1'
    and sf.QuestionID = q.QuestionID
    and sf.ResponseCode = r.ResponseCode
```

Even when I use select distinct it yields me the survey and questions with every possible answer instead  just the the question/answer combo listed in SurveyFact.

Help please?

Requested Table:
What I'm Seeing

```
| Question Number | Question Text |Response Text     |
------------------------------------------------------
|    1       |  blah blah blah    |   like           |    
|    1       |  blah blah blah    |   don't care     |
|    1       |  blah blah blah    |  hate            |
|    2       |  blah blah blah    |   like           |    
|    2       |  blah blah blah    |   don't care     |
|    2       |  blah blah blah    |   hate           |
```

What I want:

```
| Question Number | Question Text |Response Text     |
------------------------------------------------------ 
|    1       |  blah blah blah    |   don't care     |
|    2       |  blah blah blah    |   like           |
```

First one is Number, QUestion, Then every possible answer.  Second is just Number,Question, just chosen answer

Comment: could you please describe what you actually expect as a result? Make a table of the select-query, it is easier to help you then.

Comment: `on q.QuestionID = sf.QuestionID` you have no field QuestionID in SurveyFact table, so this query sould raise an error... typo or something missing ?

Comment: Added result tables (actual and wanted) and the questionCode in survey fact is the QuestionID.  Fixed it to reflect that.

Comment: your sample can't give the result you want : Response Code 3 in SurveyFact correspond to "hate" answer for question 1 and 2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    sf.QuestionID as QuestionNumber,
    q.QuestionText as QuestionText,
    r.ResponseText as Reponse
from SurveyFact sf, Question  q, Response  r
where sf.ClientID = '1'
and
sf.QuestionID = q.QuestionID
and
r.QuestionID = q.QuestionID
and
sf.ResponseCode = r.ResponseCode
```

I think is what you are looking for.

The result will be:

```
| Question Number | Question Text |Response Text     |
------------------------------------------------------ 
|    1       |  blah blah (q1)    |   hate           |
|    2       |  blah blah (q2)    |   hate           |
```

In your result you wrote:

```
| Question Number | Question Text |Response Text     |
------------------------------------------------------ 
|    1       |  blah blah blah    |   don't care     |
|    2       |  blah blah blah    |   like           |
```

But I can not see how "dont care" and "like" should be fetched?
They have ResponseCode 1 and 2.
And ResultCode 1 and 2 are not in the SurveyFact.
Well 1 is, but it is applied for question 3, and question 3 is not in the Response-table.

Comment: To answer your question about the returned results I didn't really execute the query accurately, I was just illustrating that I only wanted one result per question instead of all results per question.  And your response is what I settled on to get it fixed, so thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition that the response must be for the proper question:

```
inner join Responses r
    on r.ResponseCode = sf.ResponseCode
       and r.QuestionID = q.QuestionID
```